# Using 2 almost identical SDK in one app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I received a device with an SDK (*.h *.a files) and built a small app with it. 
Now I received a new SDK that does *almost* the same operation and the *.h file is identical to the first sdk.

The first SDK is used to do some measurements and the second does it differently. I would like to compare the results.

The question is: Can I integrate both sdk in the same app? What do I need to do?

I hope I was clear enough. If any more information is needed I'll be happy to supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding the answer is NO.

The linker needs to setup function pointers during the linking process. If the header file is the same, that also implies the signature of the functions were the same. There's no way for the linker to differentiate the function signature and setup different function pointers for the resulting binary.